# Spectral Measures: References

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am trying to learn a little bit about the spectral theory of unbounded operators but the textbook we are using (Birman and Solomyak: Spectral theory of Self-Adjoint Operators in a Hilbert Space) is a little bit heavy going for me. Is there a "gentler" book to learn about these things?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you learned about the spectral theory of bounded operators?  For those not familiar with Birman and Solomyak or your background, could you please elaborate a little on what would help make a book "gentle" enough in this context?

Comment: I'll just briefly add a comment (because I cannot tell if it will be helpful) that I like Conway's treatment in section X.4 of *A course on functional analysis*.  It builds on some previous results, including the spectral theory of bounded normal operators from Chapter IX.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't fully understand the bounded case( i.e I am just beginning to study functional analysis and perhaps should get back to this topic a bit later). I will check out Conway's book. Thanks for the reference pointer. I suppose my question can be paraphrased as follows: is there another book that discusses spectral measures and the spectral theorem based on the spectral measure's and projection valued functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I like Conway's treatment in section X.4 of *A course on functional analysis*. It builds on some previous results, including the spectral theory of bounded normal operators from Chapter IX.

I don't know if it is gentler.

Answer (score 2):

**References**

Operator theoretic treatments:

- William Arveson (Spetral Measures, Pettis Integral)*
- M. S. Birman, M. Z. Solomjak *(Spectral Measures, Pettis Integral)*
- J. Blank, P. Exner, M. Havlíček *(Spectral Measures, Pettis Integral)*
- Brian C. Hall *(Spectral Measures, Pettis Integral, Direct Integral)*
- John B. Conway *(Spectral Measures, Pettis Integral)*
- Alexander Frei *(Spectral Measures, Pettis Integral)*
- Emmanuel Kowalski *(Spectral Measures, Pettis Integral)*
- Konrad Schmüdgen *(Spectral Families, Stiltjies Integral)*

*(This list is not comprehensive!)*

**Recommendations**

Recommendations with highlights:

- M. S. Birman, M. Z. Solomjak ([Book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-009-4586-9)): Extension of Pettis Integral
- John B. Conway ([Book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3828-5)): Approximation of Normals Operators
- Alexander Frei ([Posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A79762+title%3A+Spectral+Measures)): Transformation of Normal Operators

*(This list is personal opinion.)*

**Denominations**

By spectral measures it is meant maps from Borel algebra.

By spectral families it is meant maps from real line.

**Attention**

Spectral families and Stiltjies integrals are superflous:

They seemed to arose for missing interpretion of integrals.

The modern approach exploits the Pettis integral.

*(In fact, it only imitates the Pettis integral.)*

Answer (score 0):

A very good reference is Schmüdgen: "Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space", if you want to focus on Hilbert spaces.

http://www.springer.com/en/book/9789400747524