# Reference on spectral theory for selfadjont non-compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

I cant find any book which treats spectral theory for selfadjont non-compact operators and in particular existance of eigenvectors.

I had a look in Krein and Gohberg's book from -69 but I cant find a desierd result.

Comment: If $A = \int \lambda dE(\lambda)$, then $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x\ne 0$ iff $E\{\lambda\}x = x$. This is because $AE(S) = \int \lambda dE_S(\lambda)$ where $E_S(T)=E(S\cap T)$, which forces $AE\{\lambda\}=\lambda E\{\lambda\}$.

Comment: Rudin covers this topic.

Comment: @TrialAndError Rudin proves that this is the case if $"E_{0}\ne 0"$, but we dont know this for all $\lambda_{0}$ in the spectrum

Comment: $E\{\lambda\} \ne 0$ iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. In that case, the eigenspace is the range of the orthogonal projection $E\{\lambda\}$.

Comment: Note: Selfadjoint operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space do not necessary have eigenvectors.

Comment: @TrialAndError I am aware of this and I am looking for conditions that gives exsistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a result that coverd my needs, in the last chapter of Conways "A course in F.A".

If $N$ is normal and $\lambda$ is in the complement of the essential spectra then it is a eigenvalue of finite multiplicity.

Which is what I needed. I wasnt awere of that this is essentially the "compact" part of the operator. The general case is very involved.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you loose compactness the spectral theorem doesn't just talk about eigenvalues, but the entire spectrum, which may now contain a continuous part. So there is a leap from the simple compact operator spectral theorem to the spectral theorem for bounded operators.

I personally like the treatment in say M. Reed & B. Simon "Methods of modern mathematical physics - functional analysis" (pg. ~225). Another good book is W. Rudin "Functional Analysis" (see pg. 321).

Also have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators) for the spectal theorem for bounded oparators.

**Addition:**
Seems like you are interested in eigenvalues. A word of caution must be given here. A bounded self adjoint operator may have no eigenvalues. Consider for instance $M \colon L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ given by $(Mf)(x) = xf(x)$ has no eigenvalues.

If you are interested in Schrödinger type operators i suggest (as FreeziiS.) that you look at volume IV of Reed & Simons book (it is presented as an area known as perturbation theory). Also T. Kato's book "Perturbation Theory" is worth looking at.

Comment: right, I know about spectral measures and decompostion of spectras etc. Most books I encouter only talk about the spectra and not the "nature" of the vectors in $E(\{\lambda\})\mathcal{H}$ nor thier span considering all of the spectra. But ill take a look into these two book.

Comment: I cant find any theorem treating exsitance of eigenvetors as far as I can tell. Looks like good books tho.

Comment: From the comments above I assume that you are interested in Schrödinger type operators? In that case your are looking at unbounded operators.

Comment: im interested in bounded operators

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, good references for this subject are:

"J. Blank, P. Exner, M. Havlíček, Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics"

"Brian C. Hall, Quantum Theory for Mathematicians"

You may also have a look here: [References](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1350302/79762)

Comment: you got a page number?

Comment: Basically, chapters 6, 7, (8), 9 and 10.

Comment: Ok, but on what page is the treament of existance of eigenvectors? I see that there is standrad treatment of spectral theory, but my question think is a little more subtle

Comment: Are you searching for a reference treating conditions under which the existence of suitably many eigenvectors can be guaranteed?

Comment: or any eigenvectors, but suitably many would also be intersting

Comment: Ok let me think..

Comment: Ok you may have a look into chapter 12 of "Konrad Schmüdgen, Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space" as well as chapter XIII, volume IV of "Reed & Simon, Methods of ...".

Comment: Let me know wether that helps..

Comment: I dont think there is anything in Reed/Simon. There might be in the first one its gonna take a while since I dont know all the definitions

Comment: Did you check the right **volume** of Reed & Simon???

Comment: ah thought that was chapters! thx!

Comment: No no chapter XIII of volume IV. The chapter is *reaaally* comprehensive on criteria for the behavior of spectra..

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned in the comments, but you didn't answer those comments, so I'm still not sure if you are aware that "eigenvalue" and "eigenvector" are almost useless notions when dealing with non-compact operators. Below are some examples.

1. Some selfadjoint operators have a spectral decomposition in terms of eigenvalues. For instance,  $P:\ell^2(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, given by 
   $$
   P(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)=(a_1,0,a_3,0,a_5,0,\ldots)
   $$
   is selfadjoint, has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, and it has a spectral decomposiion 
   $$
   P=1\,P+0\,(I-P).
   $$
   So the eigenspaces for $P$ are 
   $$
   \{a_1,0,a_2,0,a_3,0,\ldots):\ a\in\ell^2\},\ \ \text{ and } \{(0,a_1,0,a_2,0,\ldots):\ a\in\ell^2\}
   $$
   and it is possible to construct a basis of eigenvectors.
2. Consider, for $f\in L^\infty[0,1]$, the operator $T_f:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ given by $T_fg=fg$. It is not hard to show that $M_f$ is bounded with norm $\|f\|_\infty$, and it is selfadjoint. Its spectrum is the essential range of $f$. For $T_f$ to have an eigenvalue $\lambda$, we would need the equality 
   $$
   \lambda g=T_fg=fg
   $$
   for some $g\in L^2[0,1]$.
   It follows that $f=\lambda$ wherever $g\ne0$, and one can deduce that $f$ would have to be of the form $\lambda\,1_E+h\,1_{E^c}$. So, for example, we could have

   - $T=M_f$ with $f=1_{[0,1/2]}$, and then $f$ has eigenvalues $0,1$ and it admits a basis of eigenvectors (this is exactly the same example as in 1.).
   - $T=M_f$ with $f=1_{[0,1/2]}+x\,1_{1/2,1]}$. Here $1$ is an eigenvalue, and any function supported in $[0,1/2]$ is an eigenvector. But there are no other eigenvalues, and $T$ does not admit a basis of eigenvectors.
   - As already mentioned in the comments, if $T=M_f$ with $f$ the identity function $f(x)=x$, then $T$ has no eigenvalues at all.

Comment: I am aware of this fact. I am reading a proof which assumes that the range of $E_{A^{*}A}({\sigma_{k}})$ for some finite number of singular values, is non-empty. And further on they pick these vectors as a basis for the finite dimensional space $E_{A^{*}A} ({(\sigma_{n},\infty)})$. And cant convince myself that this is possible. The only thing we assume is that $\sigma_{n}> \sigma_{\infty}$, the essential norm.

Comment: You never mentioned that. If a singular value is greater than the essential norm, it means that it is in the "compact" part, because it is lost when passing to the Calkin algebra. So, yes, singular values greater than the essential norm are eigenvalues of $A^*A$.